# I am very confused on how to include Firebase into html

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-tools

I recently started integrating firebase into my html project, i installed firebase-tools using npm and initialized the project, but then after I included all the scripts mentioned on the firebase website, I used firebase.auth() to sign in the user, then I got an error that firebase is undefined, so I inserted these script tags into my code:

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.1/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/firebase/init.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for Analytics -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

  <!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

and below these I had my firebase config:

```
  <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "MY_API_KEY",
      authDomain: "MY_PROJECT.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://MY_PROJECT.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "MY_PROJECT",
      storageBucket: "MY_PROJECT.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "MESSAGER_ID",
      appId: "MY_APP_ID",
      measurementId: "MEASUREMENT_ID"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();
  </script>
  <script>
    async function signIn(email, password){
      await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword({
        email,
        password
      }).then(() => {window.location.href = "HomeScreen.html"}).catch((err) => {
        document.getElementById('FailedSignIn').style.display = "flex";
      })
    }
  </script>
```

And then I got these errors:

```
[2020-03-30T17:24:20.332Z] @firebase/app: Warning: Firebase is already defined in the global scope. Please make sure Firebase library is only loaded once.
Website.htmlAccess to fetch at 'https://firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/MY_PROJECT/installations' from origin 'http://localhost:63342' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
https:/…base-analytics.js:1POST https://firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/MY_PROJECT/installations net::ERR_FAILED
TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

So I would really appreciate some clarification of the ordering of these script tags, as well as how to properly initialize firebase and use it in my file without any errors.

Comment: Hi, Have you tried https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start

Comment: @MazharKhan, according to that page, I need to have the prerequisite of setting up and configuring firebase completed, which is what I'm having trouble with right now.

Comment: When posting to stack overflow, please don't share pictures of text.  You should copy the text into the question itself so it's easier to read, copy, and search.

Answer (score 0):

After you’ve created your account and the Firebase project, all you need to do is add the JavaScript code to your HTML, as described in the [Setup Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)

```
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.0.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  // Get a reference to the database service
  var database = firebase.database();

  // update the variable when the starCount is changed in the database
  var starCountRef = database.ref('posts/' + postId + '/starCount');
  starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    updateStarCount(postElement, snapshot.val());
  });

  // update the UI
  function updateStarCount(el, val) {
    el.innerHtml(`${val} Stars!`);
  }
</script>
```

Then you can continue to learn about Realtime Database [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start)

The Javascript/Node.JS SDK is introduced [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app).

Comment: I tried your code, however, it still doesn't solve the CORS issue that i received which is at the bottom of my question.

Comment: @yoyo Lemme get back to you shortly

Answer (score 0):

How do you start your local web-server at `http://localhost:63342`? 
Maybe you just have to start your web-server with using CORS request headers for external requests.

Example:

```
yarn serve --cors
```